# python -m: Error while finding module specification

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, program-entry-point

According to the python doc the `-m` flag should do the following:

> Search sys.path for the named module and execute its contents as the
>   `__main__` module.

When I run my script simply with the `python` command, everything works fine. Since I now want to import something from a higher level, I have to run the script with `python -m`. However the `__name__ == "__main__"` statement seems to return `False` and the following Error is produced:

```
/home/<name>/anaconda3/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'data.generate_dummies.py' (AttributeError: module 'data.generate_dummies' has no attribute '__path__')
```

I dont't understand what the `__path__` attribute has to do with that.

Comment: Please tell us what is the exact command you use. When running with `-m` don't call the file with `.py`.

Comment: Thanks! That already solved my problem. But what does the error message mean?

Comment: It's looking for a submodule named `py`, but `data.generate_dummies` isn't a package.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The error you get occurs when python tries to look for a package/module that does not exist. As [user2357112 mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667997/main-not-executed-when-using-python-m?noredirect=1#comment78293584_45667997), `data.generate_dummies.py` is treated as a fully specified module path (that does not exist), and an attempt is made to import a submodule `py` (that is also non-existent).

Invoke your file without `.py`, if you're using the `-m` flag, like this:

```
python -m data.generate_dummies
```