# __path__ attribute not found

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I got this error when trying to deploy my function on gcloud functions. The function runs smoothly on my local machine FYI. I've browsed some posts but none have the solution

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the similar [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55817059/15774176) and [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45668130/15774176):

> For anyone else that had this problem :
> Removing the .py suffix on the python -m command fixes this problem, it appears -m only requires module names whereas running it directly as a python file (no -m option) requires the .py suffix

To learn more about the path attribute , you can refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#module-path)

Comment: I set the entry point "main" on cloud functions, dunno why it still happens

Comment: what's error are you getting?